# Discord.py saving unknown channel messages into txt file

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author == self.user:
        return

    if message.content.lower() == 'hi':
        await message.channel.send('hello')

    if message.content.lower() == '':
        f = open("Path/To/Your/File.txt", "w")   # 'r' for reading and 'w' for writing
        f.write("" + f.name)    # Write inside file
        f.close()
```

If someone sends a message in a discord channel, and the message does not contain the word, "hi", I want it to save the unknown message into an existing text file. Without using client commands or code.

Comment: Is the message unknown if it *contains* a known term but has more content? For instance, should "Hi, how are you?" get a response or be logged? And do you want to monitor only a specific channel? ...And what do you mean by "without using code"?

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked not to receive code, but I am going to have to.
This portion:

```py
if message.content.lower() == '':
    f = open("Path/To/Your/File.txt", "w")
    f.write(""+f.name)
    f.close()
```

Seems to check if a user sends a blank message (should be impossible, since you have to send some thing in discord), and opens Path/To/Your/File.txt in write mode, and writes in the name of it (File.txt). Also, lower() makes the text lowercase, and that is not needed since you cant have an uppercase nothing.
Also, the Path/To whatever means you would have to create three folders, path, to, and your, and then put a File.txt in your. You should put a file.txt in your current folder, and change that /Path/To to just file.txt.
It does not check if the bot does not have a response.
You should completely remove that section.

Step 1:
    Create a file called like log.txt.
Step two: 
    Replace that section of code with:

```py
#checks if the bot has a response
knownmessages = ["hi"] #you can add more
if message.content not in knownmessages:
    f = open("log.txt", "a") #or what you called it. also a for append, it would overwrite otherwise.
    f.write(message.content + "\n") #\n means new line
    f.close()
```

You seem to be a beginner, so don't worry. I remember when I was a beginner.

Comment: No, sorry this is not what I meant. What I meant is, when someone sends a message, that is "unknown". For example, "What is the weather today" in a text channel, the bot is in, and the bot doesn't have a response for it. And what I want is, it getting that message, and copy + pasting it into the "log" text file.

Comment: so if the bot does not have a response, than put that in the text file?

Comment: I have edited it to do exactly that. Input what you have a response for in knownmessages, and then check the log file, and make the responses. Also, im just saying that individually making responses for each and every possible message, with mispellings, or uppercase, or spaces is very inneficient, you might want to look at machine learning, or levenshtein distance.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, I think you want to log the messages to a text file only if the bot does not have a response for it.

So here's how you could structure your `on_message` function:

Define the function as `async def on_message(self, message)`

After this you can check if you sent the message:

```
if message.author == self.user:
  return
```

Then you can add specific responses for specific strings:

```
if message.content.lower() == "hi":
  await message.channel.send("hello")
  return
```

Now's where the important part comes in:
First you create a context by using `self.get_context(message)`

After this you have to check if the context can be used to invoke a command. If yes, then the context is valid, and you can invoke the command.
If the context is invalid, then you can log the contents to a file.

```
if context.valid():
  await self.invoke(context)
  return
```

If none of these `if` clauses trigger, then that means the bot does not have a reponse for the message. So you can log it to the file.

```
with open("path/to/file.txt", 'a') as f: # a for append
  f.write(message.content + '\n')
```

So your final `on_message` method will be:

```
async def on_message(self, message):
  # Check if the bot sent the message.
  if message.author == self.user:
    return

  # Reply to some predetermined strings of text
  if message.content.lower() == "hi":
    await message.channel.send("hello")
    return
  
  # Create a context from the message
  context = await self.create_context(message)

  # If the context is valid, then invoke the command
  if context.valid:
    await self.invoke(context)
    return

  # Append to file if the bot does not have a respone to the message
  with open("path/to/file.txt", 'a') as f:
    f.write(message.content + '\n')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'MyClient' object has no attribute 'get_context'

Comment: @PikaChu Could you add the full code of the bot to the question?

Comment: @PikaChu if you are using a class that inherits `discord.Client` you can remove the code blocks which create the context and invoke it.